# My nameserver doesn't seem to be responding to queries

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind, nameserver

I setup a domain the other day and configured it to use my nameserver `ns1.mydomain.net`. Days later, my queries all respond with non-existent domain.

Here's my Bind9 config files

```
[user@host bind]$ cat named.conf.local
zone "mywebsite.com.au" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/mywebsite.com.au.db";
};

[user@host bind]$ cat /etc/bind/zones/mywebsite.com.au.db
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.mydomain.net. admin.mywebsite.com.au. (
        2006081401      ; Serial
        7200            ; Refresh
        120             ; Retry
        2419200         ; Expire
        604800          ; Default TTL
)

@       IN      NS      ns1.mydomain.net

mywebsite.com.au.         IN      A       1.1.1.1
www                       IN      A       1.1.1.1
```

The domain, `mywebsite.com.au` is using the nameserver `ns1.mydomain.net`.

When I manually query the nameserver using `nslookup www.mywebsite.com.au ns1.mydomain.net`, it replies correctly.

What could be causing the issue? Could Bind be blocking queries? That seems odd given I can query it directly.

Comment: Can you tell us what your real domain and NS are? It's looking like something's wrong with your registrar or possibly glue records.

Comment: Did you remember to do an RNDC RELOAD or restart named?

Comment: try using this tool http://www.intodns.com/ to verify your domain condition and post us a reply

Comment: @farseeker: as stupid as it sounds, I'd rather leave that as a last resort. @john: nope. Will do that now. @prix: I'll take a look at that tool now.

Comment: It seems I forgot to add a period after my nameserver deceleration in the zone file. Noticed it when intodns.com reported the nameserver as being ns1.mydomain.net.mywebsite.com.au xD

Answer (score 1):

http://www.intodns.com is a fine resource to verify a domain dns similar to dnstuff.com that is now paid.

It has helped me quiet a few times as it seems to have helped you :)...

Guess we all missed the small mistake of the period ehehe...